# Detect search bar touch objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Not related to pressing the search button, but how can I detect when the user has tapped onto the UISearchBar in iOS and Objective-C?

Comment: Have you looked at the related delegate methods?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view controller conforms to the UISearchBarDelegate and that the delegate of your UISearchBar is set. Here are the docs detailing the delegate methods for UISearchBar: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate?language=objc

You can override searchBarTextDidBeginEditing to get the functionality you want.